# OWL disjoint set of elements

Tags: owl

I am trying to create an OWL Ontology which captures the idea of a disjoint set of elements:

- I have a class `:Parent` which is all individuals that have elements that I want to ensure are disjoint.
- I have a relationship `:element`, which connects a `:Parent` to every child of that parent.  `element(p, c)` is true if p is a parent of c.
- I have a relationship `:disjoint` which is between children.  `disjoint(c1, c2)` is true if c1 and c2 are "disjoint".  Obviously `IrreflexiveProperty(:disjoint)`, as nothing can be disjoint with itself.

My goal is to create an ontology which is consistent iff for every `p`, if `p ∈ Parent` then every `:element` of `p` is `:disjoint` with every other `:element` of `p`.

The approach I've been trying is to construct a `:sibling` property such that `sibling(x, y) ↔ (x≠y) ∧ (∃p element(p, x) ∧ element(p, y))`. I was able to define a property `SubObjectProperty( ObjectPropertyChain( ObjectInverseOf( :element ) :element ) :siblingOrSelf )` which captures the set of all of the siblings I want to compare against *plus* the object itself (plus a set of `:siblingOrSelf` which are not siblings nor self, but I can ignore).  However, I cannot figure out how to derive a `:sibling` relationship which is irreflexive.  (or figure out another way to accomplish my goal)

If it is convenient for the solution, I can assume `InverseFunctionalProperty(:element)` (i.e. no child is a `:element` of two different parents).

Comment: UNA and CWA for particular class? No way :).

Comment: @StanislavKralin Is that the assumption I'm trying to make?  Dang.

Comment: Wait. You have a "parent of" relation that is called "element"? Who's designed such a vocabulary? Also, what do you mean by "disjoint"? Are children "disjoint" if they are different and not conjoined twins?

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann The children are elements of the parent.  The parent is a set, so I believe "element of" is a standard phrasing for my types.  And by disjoint I do indeed mean not conjoined.  It shouldn't matter for the question, but the particular children are intervals of time, so two intervals of time are disjoint if there is no instant that is in both intervals.

Comment: The exact meaning of disjoint is outside of the scope of the question, unless it's something that you can leverage to answer the question for my very specific cases, in which case, I beg apologies for failing to include a key part of the question.

Comment: The meaning of "disjoint" is important, because if we replaced it by an arbitrary name, such as `xyz`, then there would be absolutely no relation between it and `sibling`, that you seem to think as somehow connected. To answer your question, it seems that we need to know the relationship between `sibling` and `disjoint`, and thus, we need to understand what you mean by these names. Also, I do not see the analogy between being an element of a set (e.g., I am en element of the set of parents) and being the child of a parent (I am *not* an element of my father).

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann If I replaced `disjoint` with `foo` and `sibling` with `bar`, `element` with `baz` and `Parent` with `Thinggy`, then i would still be seeking to define a model such that, if there exists a `a` `b` and `c` such that `Thinggy(a) ∧ baz(a, b) ∧ baz(a, c) → a==b ∨ foo(a,b)`.  I was noting that I could define `bar(a,c) ↔baz(a, b)∧ baz(a, c)` as a partial solution, but I couldn't get further. If I need to change the terminology, I can.

Comment: The reason I used parent/child was because I can assume that each child has one parent, if a hierarchical relatinship offers a solution to an otherwise unsolvable problem.

Comment: I think that if I wanted to help you, I would need a few questions and answers back and forth that are not very appropriate in the form of comments to the question. I seem to remember that StackOverflow has a way of having a conversation outside the comment section but I don't know how. Anyway, one question I have is: is it possible to have `x` different from `y` but not `x` disjoint `y`?

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann StackExchange does have a chat feature, but it takes quite a few comments before it offers the chat.  As for your question, it is possible to have `x` and `y` which are different but `x` is not disjoint with `y`.  This can happen if `x` and `y` are `element`s of different Parents.  If `x` and `y` are elements of the same Parent, then `x` is different than `y` implies that `x` is disjoint with `y`.

Comment: In my specific use case, the parents are timelines, consisting of disjoint spans of time (each element in the timeline does not overlap any other element in the same timeline).  However, two different timelines may contain spans that overlap.  One timeline may have 0-3 seconds and 3-5 seconds, while the other timeline may have 0-2 seconds and 2-5 seconds.

Comment: But I can't have a single timeline with 0-3seconds and 2-5 seconds.

Comment: Another question: you said `Thinggy(a) ∧ baz(a, b) ∧ baz(a, c) → a==b ∨ foo(a,b)`, but are you sure you didn't mean `Thinggy(a) ∧ baz(a, b) ∧ baz(a, c) → b==c ∨ foo(b,c)`?

Comment: In any case, I suspect that what you want to model is not doable in OWL 2 DL. Maybe it can be done if relaxing the global constraints of OWL 2 DL, perhaps you can do it with the full expressiveness of OWL 2 Full, but you would be better off using a rule language like SWRL, or taking care of this with an ad hoc programme or script.

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann You are correct, it was a typo.  And it would be a shame if it couldn't be done in OWL 2 DL.  Although it was a good exercise, as I learned a *lot* about the expressiveness of DL trying to find ways to express it!